# Problem with communication between multer and AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, multer

I have a problem with using multer and trying to upload an image to S3 (aws)

I watched a few tutorials, read docs but I cannot find the mistake.

```
const multer = require("multer");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY_ID,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});

const awsS3 = new aws.S3();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: awsS3,
    bucket: "app-library-jaksa",
    acl: "public-read",
    metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {
        fieldName: file.fieldname
      });
    },
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    }
  })
});

module.exports = upload;
```

And then I call:

```
const multer = require("../middleware/multer");

router.post("/uploadTest", multer.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Successful", req.file);
});
```

I expect to upload the image to S3 (of course, I have a bucket and access key), but instead I get

> "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT (ip address)
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]"

Comment: I have a question, why don't you just use the aws sdk to upload the image? Is there a specific reason to use multer package?

Comment: Actually yes, the specific reason is that I didn't know that is possible. :D I need it like middleware because the example I showed is just a little piece of much more complex code, but that piece is making me a problem.

Comment: Oh ok I see the rest tag. So you want to use it as part if a rest api, maybe in an express application?

Comment: Code seems good for the first blink, you have a node connection error, are the credentials correct?? I know you have to just copy and paste, but check the region, the region name is different then the actual location, like N.Virginia is us-east-1 and etc.

Comment: Ok, I double-checked credentials before posting the problem here and I was 100% sure it is correct. Now I created new access key and used that credentials and now it is working. Very, very embarrassing. :( Thank you, Sandor, for your assistance. If you want, please write your answer below and I will accept it as correct.